# strange issue(permission error with 'civicrm_contact') while installing civicrm

Tags: wordpress, civicrm.settings.php

while installing civicrm , there is a weird permission error with table 'civicrm_contact'.
i have same setup on localhost with the same wordpress version and civicrm version.
on localhost it runs fine but on live website there is an issue.

error can be seen in screenshot [image]

Answer (score 1):

Mehta,

You will need to grant mysql user permission to create table and other necessary permission. Also can you check if username and ip are matching.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: i already have granted, whatever i could, from the backend. Still this issue persists  .I have almost hit the dead-end